# How to display the selected items in the new page?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Whenever I click on view the items are selected on same page. I need to display them on the new page, but I am not able to do that.

```
<html ng-app="countryApp">
<body ng-controller="CountryCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="x in models track by $index">
    <button ng-click="select(x, $index)">View Me</button>
  </div>

  Selected Model:

    <p> {{selected.name}} </p>
    <p> {{selected.brand}} </p>
    <p> {{selected.price}} </p>
    <p> {{selected.quan}} </p>
    <p> {{selected.sku}} </p>

</body>
```

Function:

```
<script>
  var countryApp = angular.module('countryApp', []);
  countryApp.controller('CountryCtrl', function ($scope){
    $scope.select = function(brand) {
    $scope.selected = brand;
    }
    $scope.models = [
    { brand: "Brand: Apple", id: 980190962, name: "Name: iPhone 5", price: "Price: $199", quan: "Quantity: 1", sku: "SKU:1234" }, 
    { brand: "Brand: Samsung", id: 298486374, name: "Name: Galaxy S3", price: "Price: $199", quan: "Quantity: 2", sku: "SKU:5678"}
    ]
    });

</script>
</html>
```

Comment: @ppovoski i think vinith means new view

Comment: I removed my comment in case you are correct.

Comment: @SaEChowdary  yess it has to be directed on new page.. i mean the selected models should be displayed on new page..

Comment: Should the _new page_ be a new browser tab/window that opens, a modal panel or something else?

Comment: @SamOnela it should be new tab..

Answer (score 0):

You can open new modal on click of button function like following -

In controller:

```
 $scope.showDetails = function(){
       // open new html modal to show new screen using following
       $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('templates/views/details.html',{
                scope: $scope,
                animation: 'none',
                backdropClickToClose: false
            }).then(function(modal){
                $scope.modal= modal;
                $scope.modal.show();
            });
    }
```

In HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="x in models track by $index">
    <button ng-click="showDetails (x, $index)">View Me</button>
</div>
```

By using new modal (screen) you can design as you required as well.

Comment: working onit.. but how do i bind my selected model list to showdetails?/

Comment: it will take by default your selected modal(just access your modal like - $scope.modalName).

if not you can use get set method using factory

Answer (score 0):

You can use two options either store that selected user to localstorage or somewhere and read that in details view like

```
localStorage.setItem('myObj',JSON.stringify(brand));
```

and retrieve that in details view like

```
JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('myObj'));
```

OR

I will prefare to use parent child relationship in this suppose you have a parent controller named '**CountryCtrl**' and two child controllers '**CountryListCtrl**' and '**CountryDetailCtrl**'. List page is bind to 'CountryListCtrl' and details view is bind to '**CountryDetailCtrl**' and on top you have '**CountryCtrl**'. You can change your view using ng-include etc. When moving from List to Detail Controller set an object on parent controller and it will be accessible to both Controllers. You can learn about parent and child relationship in angularjs on internet there are tons of article available.

Thanks.

Comment: i have less than 15 reputations so even if i mark that wont make a change..

Answer (score 0):

To show the details of the selected item in a new tab, there are multiple ways to achieve this. One way is to add a form with attribute `target="_blank"` (to open the *action* attribute in a new tab) and submit it in the `select()` function.

So you can add a form, like this:

```
<form id="openNewTabForm" target="_blank" method="GET"></form>
```

Then update the function to submit the form. There are multiple ways to pass the data about the selected phone - e.g. store the data in form fields, serialize the data and store it in a cookie, in localStorage, etc. Here is an example using hidden form fields:

```
$scope.select = function(phone) {
    var form = document.getElementById('openNewTabForm');
    form.action = action="selectedPhone.html";
    Object.keys(phone).forEach(function(field,index) {
      var input = form.elements[field]; //look for an existing form field for this field
      if (input) { //update existing form field
        input.value = phone[field];
      }
      else { //create a new form field for this 
        input = document.createElement('input');
        input.type = 'hidden';
        input.name = field;
        input.value = phone[field];
        form.appendChild(input);
      }
    });
    form.submit();
    $scope.selected = phone;
}
```

Then have a new page (e.g. *selectedPhone.html*) that takes the values submitted with the form. This could be a server-side page (e.g. with PHP, Ruby, etc), in which case you would set the attribute `method="POST"` on the form. Or you can just use a regular HTML page and process the query string. You could also use AngularJS + [UI Router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router), VueJS, etc. to modify the URL after it has been loaded.

Take a look at [this Plunker example I made](http://plnkr.co/edit/jtd578KRF538pCYZStlP?p=preview) for an example. I would have included a code snippet that would run here but SO doesn't (currently) allow having a form submission open a new tab because it is sand-boxed.

Another approach might be to use [window.open()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open) for opening a new browser window but that might lead to issues with popup blockers for some users.